# How could I could refactor a Pundit Policy to make it more DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry, pundit

I'm new to using Pundit with Rails and have a new policy for my Artist model that is working as I expect it to, but I'm not clear on a good way to refactor it to make it more DRY. Specifically, it seems that I'm calling `authorize @artist` way too many times in `artists_controller.rb` and that there's a lot of code duplication in my `artist_policy.rb`.

For context, an Artist has a name, such as "Claude Monet" and that's it.

Here's my artist_policy.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/799d5f9136b92fcf92c6074e6a28bfdb

And, my application_policy.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/09d37a42c6f2500f98be3f1518c945e9

And here's my artists_controller.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/c0dd8f33416b002f3b4c9a7baf0a3a75

And, models/artist.rb:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/c190322af41f3e91739b53391d8b7834

Is the way I currently have it working ok because I'm clearing expressing each policy (in the same way that some duplicate code across integration tests is ok), or should I refactor this? If so, is there a standard way that people structure their Pundit policies that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems that I'm calling `authorize @artist` way too many times in `artists_controller.rb`

Honestly, I think what you have there is fine.

There are a few ways that you *could* try to be clever about this and "automatically call `authorize`" for each controller action, but *(warning: opinion-based answer)* from past experience I've found that such attempts to make it more DRY adds significant confusion. Especially when you end up writing some controller action(s) that don't need authorising, or need authorising in an unusual way.

> There's a lot of code duplication in my `artist_policy.rb`

One step at time... Here's the original:

```
class ArtistPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :artist

  def initialize(user, artist)
    @user   = user
    @artist = artist
  end

  def create?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor?
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def update?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == @artist.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def destroy?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == @artist.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

It's unnecessary to define your own `initialize` method like that, so long as you're happy to reference the more generic variable name: `record`, instead of `artist` (which should be defined in the `ApplicationPolicy`):

```
class ArtistPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def create?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor?
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def update?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == record.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def destroy?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == record.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Next, in situations like this, it's fine to reference one policy rule from another - so long as they apply equally to user types:

```
class ArtistPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def create?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor?
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def update?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == record.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def destroy?
    update?
  end
end
```

Next, note that the `record.user_id` **is** the logged in user, for the create action! So you can simplify this even further:

```
class ArtistPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def create?
    if user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == record.user_id
      true
    elsif user.banned?
      false
    end
  end

  def update?
    create?
  end

  def destroy?
    create?
  end
end
```

And lastly, the logic in that method is actually little wrong. (You could have picked this up with tests...) If a user is an admin **and** they are banned, then you still presumably want this to return `false`, not `true`. With this in mind, we can fix + simplify the code again to:

```
class ArtistPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def create?
    return false if user.banned?
    user.admin? || user.moderator? || user.contributor? && user.id == record.user_id
  end

  def update?
    create?
  end

  def destroy?
    create?
  end
end
```

Comment: You *could* simplify this even further, but I wouldn't bother unless you find this logic gets repeated a lot *elsewhere* in the application. For example, you could define a method: `User#admin_or_moderator?`, and you could also define a method in the `ApplicationPolicy`, e.g. `record_belongs_to_contributor?`.

Comment: Thanks so much Tom! This is an incredibly helpful answer. Really appreciate you taking the time to walk me through it step-by-step. Learned a lot in that.

Comment: You could also use `alias_method` now. https://github.com/varvet/pundit#just-plain-old-ruby